# Aurelia - Karma error

Tags: aurelia

I am following the [Aurelia docs for Production setup](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/a-production-setup) and I am encountering an issue with the the **Running The Unit Tests** section.

I have the app running with no issues. I open a new terminal window and successfully installed karma-cli 3.9.3. But when I run `gulp test` I get the following error:

`31 05 2016 15:58:09.929:INFO [Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.5)]: Connected on socket /#kJiah_Vi_OxBaoMGAAAA with id 68824261
Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.5) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
  at /Users/XXX/Documents/Websites/Aurelia/Production/node_modules/karma-jspm/src/adapter.js:18`

I know enough that I should not be editing any source files in node_modules, so how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Can you show your karma config?

Comment: Try to start karma directly. Open terminal on the project root and  "Karma start"